# view_func.__module__ suddenly broken

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-middleware

I have a **process_view** middleware that sets the module and view names into the request like this:

```
class ViewName( object ):
    def process_view( self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs ):
        request.module_name = view_func.__module__
        request.view_name = view_func.__name__
```

I use the names together as a key for session based pagination.

But as of yesterday, for reasons I am unable to discover,
**view_func.__module__** now returns 'cp.models', which is a model file in
one of my apps.

I've gone back one commit at a time trying to find the cause.  The issue is still there even after reverting code to more than a month ago.

I'm seeing only two python packages changed recently on the server, my app uses neither, and the updates were more than a month ago:

```
cat /var/log/dpkg.log*|grep "upgrade" |grep python
2013-01-25 03:41:05 upgrade python-problem-report 2.0.1-0ubuntu15.12.0.1-0ubuntu17.1
2013-01-25 03:41:06 upgrade python-apport 2.0.1-0ubuntu15.1 2.0.1-0ubuntu17.1
```

I also tried rearranging my middleware list, didn't help.

Any idea what else might be causing this issue?